# add custom rows in the select statemen in sql

Tags: sql, select

I have a sql statement that combines values from a row from table and the final result has one column with a computed string.Example:

```
select Value1 + ' and ' + Value2 +' and another string' from MyTable
```

and the result would be

```
m1 and n1 and another string
m1 and n2 and another string
```

How can I update my query to add a fixed string on each row after the computed value from my table. I want to have something like(the new string needs to be on a new line):

```
m1 and n1 and another string
test
m1 and n2 and another string
test
```

I'm using sql server 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `cross apply` the extra row with a `values` table constructor:

```sql
select v.Value
from MyTable t
cross apply (values
    (Value1 + ' and ' + Value2 +' and another string'),
    ('test')
) as v(Value)
```

Each row goes inside a set of `()`, columns separated by `,` and doing it as an `apply` instead of `join` means you can access outer columns.

Comment: works like a charm. It seems that it's time to read again some sql books. Thank you.

Comment: @BudaGavril . . . Note that without an `order by` this is not guaranteed to return the results in any particular order.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an ordering mechanism to guarantee reproducible order of your output. Here is one way

```
with cte1 (value1, value2) as 

(select 'm1', 'n1' 
 union all 
 select 'm1', 'n2'),

cte2 (col_1, row_num) as

(select value1 + 'and' + value2 + 'another string', row_number() over (order by value1) 
 from cte1),

cte3 (col_1, row_num) as

(select col_1, row_num 
 from cte2 
 union all
 select 'test', row_num + 0.5    --to sandwich the 'test' between rows
 from cte2)

select col_1
from cte3
order by row_num;
```

---

If you wish to use a more compact version

```
select col_1 
from (select *, value1 + 'and' + value2 + 'another string' as col_1 
      from t
      union all
      select *, 'test' 
      from t) a
order by value1, value2, case when col_1 = 'test' then 1 else 0 end asc;
```